# pandas сортировка по столбцам

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка

Есть DF:

| IDs | Names | group | Projects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TIRL002 | WebSupp1 | 0 | KLL-0223 |
| TIRL003 | WebSupp1 | 0 | KLL-0224 |
| TIRL004 | WebSupp1 | 0 | KLL-0225 |
| TIRL005 | WebSupp3 | 11 | KLL-0226 |
| TIRL006 | WebSupp3 | 11 |  |
| TIRL007 | WebSupp3 | 11 |  |
| TIRL008 | WebSupp4 | 22 |  |
| TIRL009 | WebSupp4 | 22 |  |
| TIRL010 | WebSupp4 | 22 |  |
| TIRL011 | WebSupp5 | 33 |  |
| TIRL013 | WebSupp5 | 33 |  |
| TIRL014 | WebSupp5 | 33 |  |

В нем есть столбец "group" с уникальными значениями для определенных IDs. На основе этих уникальных значений я хочу дуплицировать и растянуть значения в Projects так, чтобы, например, первый проект "KLL-0223" продолжался до конца "0", потом начиная с 11 - "KLL-0224" и т.д

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать:

| IDs | Names | group | Projects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TIRL002 | WebSupp1 | 0 | KLL-0223 |
| TIRL003 | WebSupp1 | 0 | KLL-0223 |
| TIRL004 | WebSupp1 | 0 | KLL-0223 |
| TIRL005 | WebSupp3 | 11 | KLL-0224 |
| TIRL006 | WebSupp3 | 11 | KLL-0224 |
| TIRL007 | WebSupp3 | 11 | KLL-0224 |
| TIRL008 | WebSupp4 | 22 | KLL-0225 |
| TIRL009 | WebSupp4 | 22 | KLL-0225 |
| TIRL010 | WebSupp4 | 22 | KLL-0225 |
| TIRL011 | WebSupp5 | 33 | KLL-0226 |
| TIRL013 | WebSupp5 | 33 | KLL-0226 |
| TIRL014 | WebSupp5 | 33 | KLL-0226 |

Comment: Пока вы пытаетесь только рисовать. Согласно требованиям этого форума вы должны привести  воспроизводимый пример данных и тот код, которым вы пытались решить вашу задачу. Тогда вам помогут и ошибки исправить и решение в случае необходимости найти.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Да, я согласен, но мне нужна помощь только с этим шагом и по этому я спросил совет приведя маленький пример сверху.

Answer (score 1):

Решение моей проблемы:

```
df_group["Project names"] = df_group.groupby("group").ngroup().map(projects["Projects"])
```

```
projects = pd.DataFrame({"Projects": ["KLL023","KLL024","KLL025","KLL026"]})
```